# How to use Firestore DocumentID __name__ in query

Tags: go, google-cloud-firestore, gcloud

I plan to use the "in" query selector to return several documents based on a list of IDs. However I've simplified to use "==" for this example:

```
collection := server.Firestore.Collection("foo")

// Add a document:

ref, _, err := collection.Add(ctx, map[string]string{"a": "b"})
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

// Here's the document ID:

fmt.Println("ref.ID", ref.ID)

// Get all the documents in the collection just to check it's there:

allDocs, err := collection.Query.Documents(ctx).GetAll()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println("len(allDocs):", len(allDocs))

// Check our document is the one in the collection:

fmt.Println("allDocs[0].Ref.ID", allDocs[0].Ref.ID)

// Get the document using __name__ query:

docQuery, err := collection.Query.Where(firestore.DocumentID, "==", ref.ID).Documents(ctx).GetAll()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println("len(docQuery):", len(docQuery))
```

Output:

```
ref.ID NF3CCjDikC9iHPubGA8o
len(allDocs): 1
allDocs[0].Ref.ID NF3CCjDikC9iHPubGA8o
len(docQuery): 0
```

As far as I can tell, the code above should return one document in the query. Am I using the DocumentID ("__ name __") selector incorrectly?

Comment: How did you define `firestore` that you used in `firestore.DocumentID`?

Comment: DocumentID is a const string in the firestore package with the value `__name__`

Comment: Try removing the `.GetAll()` of your query. Let me know if it works.

Comment: This doesn't work... the iterator returns `iterator.Done`.

Comment: OK so more information. I was using the firestore emulator for this test. I've just tried deploying to the production, and I'm getting the following error from the last query: `rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = __key__ filter value must be a Key`

Comment: OK I've worked it out. `Where(firestore.DocumentID, "==", ref)` - e.g. passing the whole `*firestore.DocumentRef` instead of the `string` works in both the emulator and the production Firestore. Passing a string fails on both but in the emulator it fails silently and returns no error and no results.

Answer (score 5):

OK I've worked it out. Changing the final query to:

```
Where(firestore.DocumentID, "==", ref)
```

... e.g. passing the whole `*firestore.DocumentRef` instead of the `string` works in both the emulator and the production Firestore.

Passing a string returns no results in both environments, but when using the emulator it fails silently and returns no error.